# How to store docx or pdf file uniquely and retrieve it in oracle db

Tags: java, oracle

I m working on a web application where user can store a file and if they want they can replace the old file with a new one. I m using Java for backend, Angular 4 for frontend and oracle db. Can i store the file as it is in oracle db in the table or I should use something else.  Thank you

Comment: well, you can use BLOB column to store anything in a database, what are you really asking about is how to perform uniquity check on the data? @Prince Kumar

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you share a code or elaborate on getting the file from front end and store it in db.

Comment: Not really because it depends on what framework are you using (JDBC plain, JPA ...) you need to explain your self more in the question.

Comment: I m using Hibernate framework & Rest API. The table will contain file id, file itself, creator, date, status and other columns. In the front end there will be a form which will contain all inputs for the columns. The form will be sent as a object to back-end. I m stuck on how to work with the file. For normal text i can just set the values in the entity class object but how to work with file?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the official oracle doc you can use a `BLOB` type.

Maybe a better solution is that you can save the file locally and put only the path to the database.

[Link to the oracle doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)